# Comparing (alphanumeric) character strings in R

Tags: r, compare, alphanumeric

Consider the following:

```
"16D" < "7A"
```

returns TRUE.

Why is that and how can I compare such character strings such that the number is compared first then the letter? This way the answer would be false because 16>7 and D>A?

Comment: As to '*why is that?*' - Alphanumeric order - see: `sort(c("7A","16D","200Y"))`

Comment: Why is that? String comparisons test the first character that does not match. Here, "1" is less than "7".

Answer (score 5):

Can you adapt this?

```
library("gtools")
(m <- mixedorder(c("16D","7A")))
## [1] 2 1
m[1] < m[2] ## FALSE
```

Comment: it does work. But what I actually have is a column of such alphanumerics that I need to categorize. For example I want to assign a label for those >= "0A" & < "7A".

Comment: can you revise your question/add details/make your question reproducible so we know what the target task is?